# Simple software for mapping residential address in Singapore

Tags: geocoding, software-recommendations, address

I am new to GIS and I recently have a project where we will like to map clinic addresses vs patients' address, to show the distance between these locations.

In addition, at each clinic address, a number of patients would have visited for either chronic or acute visit. I will like to be able to illustrate the different type (acute or chronic) of visits, as well as the number of visits (9 acute vs 5 chronic for Clinic XXX).

Lastly, we will need to do this on a regular basis (meaning we will have a continuous feed of address that we will key in periodically), and also to layer the different maps (options to select, unselect layers).

Is there any simple freeware or software out there that can readily do this? My colleague has recently learnt ArcGIS, but I feel that it's an overkill.

Comment: If you're prepared to do the hard work yourself (finding addresses and placing/attributing points) then I see no reason why QGIS wouldn't work for you. You should be able to obtain cadastre (property boundaries) over your area and use OpenStreetMap for roads/rail for extra visual appeal. The only thing difficult about this would be designing the table  to fit all the fields you need and working out *street distance* traveled as opposed to a direct distance (if that is important).

Comment: QGIS is very powerful like ArcGIS, but it is free - so who cares about overkill as the simple functions are easy to use and you can ignore anything else.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Mappa, may I ask if Google Maps will be able to achieve the same things?